# How do parse string as JSON in Logic App?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, json-deserialization

I have JSON below which I receive from external entity. As you can see `requestbody` parameter is appearing as `string` even though it's JSON. So how do I unescape it so I can correctly parse it downstream?

```
{
  "emailaddress": "174181@mycomp.com",
  "requestbody": "{\"Id\":\"57518139-687c-4223-b08b-342f4ff426ca\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"d701e7aa-5a0a-4c4a-81be-4c4b7a3967ce\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f\"}}"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use a Parse JSON Action as shown below:

**Content:**

```
{
  "emailaddress": "174181@mycomp.com",
  "requestbody": "{\"Id\":\"57518139-687c-4223-b08b-342f4ff426ca\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"d701e7aa-5a0a-4c4a-81be-4c4b7a3967ce\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f\"}}"
}
```

**Schema**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "properties": {
        "emailaddress": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "requestbody": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "emailaddress",
        "requestbody"
    ],
    "type": "object"
}
```

[image: ParseJson]

2. Initialize Variable

```cs
-Name = Variable Name
-Type = Object
-Value = json(body('Parse_JSON')['requestbody'])
```

[image]

3. Now you can extract the properties of your Json string as shown below:

```
variables('jsonobj')?['Properties']
```

[image]

Full Code view of my sample:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "jsonobj",
                            "type": "Object",
                            "value": "@json(body('Parse_JSON')['requestbody'])"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": {
                        "emailaddress": "174181@mycomp.com",
                        "requestbody": "{\"Id\":\"57518139-687c-4223-b08b-342f4ff426ca\",\"Properties\":{\"PrincipalId\":\"d701e7aa-5a0a-4c4a-81be-4c4b7a3967ce\",\"RoleDefinitionId\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635\",\"Scope\":\"/subscriptions/64ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f\"}}"
                    },
                    "schema": {
                        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
                        "properties": {
                            "emailaddress": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "requestbody": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "emailaddress",
                            "requestbody"
                        ],
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@variables('jsonobj')?['Properties']",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use this expression:

```
@json(outputs('Mock_example_data').requestbody)
```

Below is an example using a `Compose` action to mock up your data and another `Compose` action as a simple proof of concept.

[image]

Comment: what about its an array ?

Comment: You can wrap the input in the array() workflow function if the json() function does  not work.